# seasonality and trend on exogeneous variables

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I am working on a time series project. 
I would like to add exogeneous variables on my regression. The exogeneous variables have a seasonnal component and I don't know if it is necessary to eliminate the seasonality and then to include the variable on the regression or simply to include the exogeneous variable on the regression. 
Is there someone who can help me? Is there some econometrics references? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: is it a question for stats.stackexchange ?

Comment: Maybe I don't know this website. I'll have a look on this website.

Answer (score 0):

As a start, if you are looking for a guide to the computation, you might have a look at this excellent [external reference which lists out lots of packages which can be very useful for time series analysis](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html).

Additionally, you might also have a look at this brief description on [exogenous variables](http://www-personal.umd.umich.edu/~delittle/Encyclopedia%20entries/exogenous%20variable.pdf). In general, every regression model first assumes that all independent regression variables are exogenous.

You might also want to have a look at [this other excellent resource which talks about time series analysis & de-seazonalization](http://www.math.mrt.ac.lk/TMJAC/Time%20Series%20Analysis/TS%20_lecture%201%20_.pdf). I would suggest that, before you do any variable selection on the time series, you de-seasonalize it. This simple act can allow you to get a picture of the trend of the data & flatten it so that you can objectively look at the predictions between groups.